# Kartik DateRangePicker with two attributes cause invalidDateFormat and NaN on range date selection

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app, bootstrap-daterangepicker, kartik-v

I've a question about the Kartik DateRangePicker Widget that i use in my gridview for filter some results.

in my SearchModel i've created two attributes

```
    public $date_start;
    public $date_end;
```

i use these for filter a field in database 'insert_date'.

In my view, as grid configuration, i've set these options

```
[
            'attribute' => 'insert_date',
            'options' => ['class' => 'gridview-date-column'],
            'filter' => DateRangePicker::widget([
                'model' => $searchModel,
                'name' => 'insert_date',
                'attribute' => 'insert_date',
                'startAttribute' => 'date_start',
                'endAttribute' => 'date_end',
                'convertFormat'=>true,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'opens'=>'right',
                    'locale' => [
                        'cancelLabel' => 'Clear',
                        'format' => 'd-m-Y',
                    ],
                ]
            ]),
            'format' => ['date', Yii::$app->formatter->datetimeFormat],
            'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'min-width: 200px;'] 
        ],
```

By default $date_start and $date_end haven't a value, so , when i enter in my view and try to filter this field i get an 'invalidDate' error and a series of **NaN** on the calendars.

This is fixed if i set a value for these two fields or if remove them from the configuration ( so i can only use insert_date attribute as string with these two ranges for filtering ).

Looking in the plugin repository i've found the [same case](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-date-range/issues/81) and as response of the author

> This problem occurs because you have an invalid date format for the data that does not match the plugin's format.

But as empty these fields can never have a correct data format.

Someone had the same problem?
Thanks in advance for all the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution:

In Kartik plugin there's a Behavior Model that i can include in my searchModel:

```
use kartik\daterange\DateRangeBehavior;
```

Then i can instantiate it overriding behaviors() method:

```
public $date_start;
public $date_end;

public function behaviors() {
    return [
        [
            'class' => DateRangeBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'insert_date',
            'dateStartAttribute' => 'date_start',
            'dateEndAttribute' => 'date_end',
            'dateStartFormat' => 'd-m-Y',
            'dateEndFormat' => 'd-m-Y',

        ]
    ];
}
```

and in the search() method:

```
public function search($params)
{
   // Some other filters
   if($this->date_start && $this->date_end) {
      // filtered query
   }
}
```

Hope this can help someone else.